# Docker + Nodejs + Private Repo + Private NPM Module - Access Problems

Tags: node.js, ssh, npm, docker, boot2docker

I am in process of setting up the the deployment of a Node.js Service with Docker.

The Dockerfile I have is pieced together from various examples from around the net.
The directory for the Dockerfile includes:

- Dockerfile
- id_rsa
- start.sh

This is the Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:13.10

# make sure apt is up to date
RUN apt-get update

# install npm, git, ssh, curl
RUN apt-get install -y npm git git-core ssh curl

RUN mkdir /nodejs && curl http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.31/node-v0.10.31-linux-x64.tar.gz | tar xvzf - -C /nodejs --strip-components=1

# Fixes empty home
ENV PATH $PATH:/nodejs/bin

ENV HOME /root

# SSH SETUP
RUN mkdir -p /root/.ssh
ADD id_rsa /root/.ssh/id_rsa
RUN chmod 700 /root/.ssh/id_rsa
RUN echo "IdentityFile /root/.ssh/id_rsa" >> /root/.ssh/ssh_config
RUN ssh-keyscan github.com >> /root/.ssh/known_hosts

ADD start.sh /tmp/

RUN chmod +x /tmp/start.sh

CMD ./tmp/start.sh
```

After the set-up is complete, start.sh runs and I experience problems with a private NPM dependency that the private Node.js service has. This is what start.sh is doing:

```
cd /tmp

# try to remove the repo if it already exists
rm -rf MediaFX; true

git clone https://<username>:<password>@github.com/company/ExampleRepo.git

cd RepoName

node --version

ls

npm install

NODE_ENV=test DEBUG=* PORT=3000 node server.js
```

In package.json for ExampleRepo, there is one private module that we import like this:

```
"dependencies": {
    "scribe": "git+ssh://git@github.com:Company/PrivateDep.git"
},
```

When npm install gets to this repo, it outputs these logs:

```
npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:InboxAppCo/scribe.git Cloning into bare repository '/root/.npm/_git-remotes/git-github-com-InboxAppCo-scribe-git-abae334a'...
npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:InboxAppCo/scribe.git
npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:InboxAppCo/scribe.git Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '192.30.252.130' to the list of known hosts.
npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:InboxAppCo/scribe.git Permission denied (publickey).
npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:InboxAppCo/scribe.git fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:InboxAppCo/scribe.git
npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:InboxAppCo/scribe.git Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:InboxAppCo/scribe.git and the repository exists.
npm ERR! Error: `git "clone" "--mirror" "git@github.com:InboxAppCo/scribe.git" "/root/.npm/_git-remotes/git-github-com-InboxAppCo-scribe-git-abae334a"` failed with 128
npm ERR!     at ChildProcess.cpclosed (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/exec.js:59:20)
npm ERR!     at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
npm ERR!     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:789:12)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://bugs.debian.org/npm>
npm ERR! or use
npm ERR!     reportbug --attach /tmp/MediaFX/npm-debug.log npm

npm ERR! System Linux 3.16.4-tinycore64
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /tmp/MediaFX
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.15
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.18
```

I thought that since the git clone of the private Node service works fine, any of its private NPM dependencies would install smoothly.

I am fairly positive that my SSH set up is flawed (and that it didn't manifest its self while git cloning the private parents repo) because I added username and password to the link. However, I am unsure and would appreciate some guidance on how to do this correctly.

Comment: For one thing, you need the openssh and ca-certificate packages.   Also, try running your container interactively and stepping though everything to figure these things out.

docker run -it <container> /bin/bash

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`git clone https://<username>:<password>@github.com/company/ExampleRepo.git`

Works, because you are passing the `username` and `password` and doing it over `https`

```
"dependencies": {
    "scribe": "git+ssh://git@github.com:Company/PrivateDep.git"
},
```

Fails, because you are connecting directly over `ssh` and Docker doesn't do any `ssh agent` forwarding from the host machine.

Unfortunatly it dosen't look like npm supports any url format to send username and password like your clone line: https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#git-urls-as-dependencies

You'd have to add your ssh keys to the docker container ( Not Reccomended )

Or do something funky like share you SSH_SOCKET from the host like:

https://gist.github.com/d11wtq/8699521

Answer (score 2):

Here's an approach I'm going to try implementing this evening:

```
docker create --build-arg TOKEN <my priv token> <dockerFile>
```

maybe declare the arg in the docker file?

```
ARG TOKEN
```

then in the script have npm install use that TOKEN in dependencies

```
"privModule": "git+https://${TOKEN}:x-oauth-basic@github.com/<githubID>/<privateModule>.git"
```

and if that doesn't work, somehow replace that var in the package.json (with sed) or have npm use an environment var.